# Different resources.xml for test in Grails?

Tags: grails, testing

I have `resources.xml` under `grailsApp/conf/spring` folder and all the bean get initialized, but what I wish to have different bean definitions for test Vs Actual.

Can I have a separate `test-resources.xml` and load it only during the test, while loading `resources.xml` otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you confined to using XML for bean definitions? Using `resources.groovy` is the preferred approach now as it provides a powerful [DSL](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#springdsl) where it's simple to define beans depending on the environment:

```
import grails.util.Environment

beans = {
    switch(Environment.current) {
        case Environment.TEST:
            myBean(String, "test string")
            break

        case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
            myBean(String, "dev string")
            break
    }
}
```

You can see further examples in the documenation on [Grails and Spring](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/spring.html#springdslAdditional).

#### Option 2

If you're not able to use the Grails Spring DSL for the bean definitions, you could use a sort of hybrid approach. Move resources.xml out of `conf/spring/` and somewhere else on the classpath. Next to it, create another XML file that holds your bean definitions for the test environment, let's call it `resources-test.xml`. Then add a resources.groovy file to `conf/spring/` with something like this:

```
import grails.util.Environment

beans = {

    switch(Environment.current) {
        case Environment.TEST:
            importBeans('classpath:/resources-test.xml')
            break

        case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
            importBeans('classpath:/resources.xml')
            break
    }

}
```

This approach allows you to keep your bean definitions in XML but utilize the Grails Spring DSL to switch on the environment.

#### Option 3

Depending on the complexity and number of beans you're dealing with in your resources.xml, perhaps you could make use of a [`BeanFactoryPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html). Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor allows you to hook into beans before they've been initialized so that you can modify their definitions. You would need to create a class in `src/groovy` that implements `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` like so:

```
import grails.util.Environment
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConstructorArgumentValues

class CustomBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    @Override
    void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        if (Environment.current == Environment.TEST) {
            BeanDefinition definition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition('myBean')
            ConstructorArgumentValues constructorArgs = definition.constructorArgumentValues
            constructorArgs.clear()
            constructorArgs.addGenericArgumentValue("Modified for test")
        }
    }
}
```

And then register it in resources.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">

<beans>
    <bean id="myBean" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="this will be overwritten" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="postProcessor" class="CustomBeanFactoryPostProcessor" />
</beans>
```

This is obviously a very trivial example, but when running tests, the myBean value will be set to `"Modified for test"` instead of `"this will be overwritten"`.

#### Option 4

An alternative to defining the beans separately for each environment is to override the beans inside of the test classes themselves by adding a `doWithSpring` closure:

```
static doWithSpring = {
    myBean(String, 'Modified for test')
}

void "test bean is overridden"() {
    expect:
    grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('myBean') == 'Modified for test'
}
```

Comment: Remarkable elaborate explanation. Couldn't have asked for more.

Thanks a bunch